# How would you interpret this aggregation algorithm found in this mobile data packet tracking research paper?

Tags: android, algorithm, networking, network-programming

I am a little new to reading algorithms and I stumped trying to decipher this algorithm. The context for the algorithm is to infer the hand off decision logic for each serving cell.

```
Input: G =FSM of handoff logic, Ξ = {e} with all transitions in (b);
for e(vs r−→ vd) ∈ Ξ do
    if vs ∈ G AND vd ∈ G then
        Find e ∈ G satisfying vs r−→ vd and update r = r ∪ r;
    else if vs ∈/ G AND vd ∈/ G then
        Ge = {e}, G = G ∪ Ge; //e is the only edge in an isolated Ge
    else // vs or vd ∈ G, assume vs ∈ G for simplicity
        G = G ∪ e by adding vd and the edge e into G
    end if
end for
```

This is the image for the algorithm which I was referring to

[image: 1]

This is the research paper which I am referring to, at page 7:
http://metro.cs.ucla.edu/papers/mobicom16-mobileinsight.pdf

Please do let me now if there is an easier way for me to decipher this algorithm or the meaning of the notations.
Thanks

Comment: This should be asked in https://cs.stackexchange.com/, since there is no "real" code involved.

Comment: It seems to me that on that very page 7, the paragraph starting "Algorithm 1 shows the pseudo-code for aggregation", and the one after it, are an explanation of the algorithm...

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand FSMs, where FSM stands for *Finite State State Machine*. An FSM is a collection of states and transitions between the states, similar to a *graph* consisting of vertices and edges. (The style of this algorithm description is much like a graph algorithm, calling the FSM *G* for instance, which usually is short for graph.) *v→w* means a transition from state *v* to state *w*, and if there's an *r* above the arrow, it means that *r* is the symbol consumed from the input that makes this particular transition be chosen among the ones that leave *v*.

You also need to understand notation of set operations (in case you don't already), *x*∈*S* meaning that *x* is an element of *S*, *S*∪*T* meaning the *union* of sets *S* and *T*, and so on.

Describing all of this is too much for a Stack Overflow answer, but look for information on FSMs and set theory notation in maths/algorithms books or on the internet.